# Fade DIV with childrens to black and vice versa with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking for an effect similar to jQuery UI tabs opacity toggle.

```
$('#content').tabs({
    fx: {
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }
});
```

How is it done? How can i fade a div (variable height, gradient background) and its children to black, replace its content and fade it back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options abound:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

good examples with specifics at each topic.

this link too gives example using opacity - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/apply-50-opacity-to-a-div

Comment: I now use a black wrapping div and fading out my content div. Thanks for the hint! I still would prefer a solution without a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The background color can be animated if you use the [color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)

From the jQuery docs:

> ### Animation Properties and Values
>
> All animated properties should be
> animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most
> properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery
> functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but
> background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).
> Property values are treated as a number of p

Comment: I´m using background-image to set my gradients which seems not supported by the color plugin.